# How to propagate backbone stopListening to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks, marionette, backbone-events

**TLDR;** With Backbone events, is there a way to fire some code when an event object has no more listeners?

I have a Backbone Marionette View listening to change events on `Model A`. When I'm done with the view, I call `view.close()` which causes it to stop listening to all events on `Model A`. If this model is not referenced by anything else it now can be garbage collected.

However my problem is that `Model A` is listening to change events on `Model B` which in turn is listening to real time updates from a web socket.

So when `Model A` stops listening to `Model B`, it can be released, but `Model B` will still be held in memory due to the web socket having a callback. Adding a `modelB.close()` method doesn't necessarily work, as other objects may still be using `Model B`. But if no other object is using that instance of `Model B`, then I would like it to trigger it's `stopListening` method, which would then in turn let the web socket know it can close when nothing is listening to it any more.

**Edit:**
Solution based upon answer; https://gist.github.com/DomBlack/6885740
Example use;

```
var BackboneExt = require('/path/to/gist');

var modelB = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        BackboneExt.autoCleanup(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All EventAggregators are implemented in such a way, that someone possesses a list of callback functions that are to be executed in certain 'events'. If an object exposes an EventAggregator API, that means, it effectively offers a list into which anyone can write it's name and e-mail and the reason when and how you want to be contacted. Usually, you aren't just handed the list and a pen, but a you need to fill out a registration form, which will then be processed by a third person, and if you pass all validation criteria, you will be put onto that list by that third person. Same if you want to unsubscribe yourself from that list.

Now, who has that list? Well, anyone offering its own EventAggrigator API has such a list. So if your modelB offers an EventAggregator API to other modules, that means it has the list with all the subscribers. If that list should be empty, which modelB can check, it can go and tell someone else, e.g. your websocket module.

Comment: Backbone's models extend the Events class, so as such `model B` already has a list of callbacks it can check. The problem is knowing when to check that list; as the `off` function within `Backbone.Events` does not trigger a `callbackRemoved` event.

Comment: You have to extend `Backbone.Events`' `off` method with a trigger that is fired when (1) the `off` method is executed and (2) the list then contains 0 entries. In order to register that callback function, you need to attach it as a property to something that both `Backbone.Events` and `modelB` have access to.

Comment: I was sort of hoping somebody had already extended Backbone, but I've created a solution see; https://gist.github.com/DomBlack/6885740